# Checkbox Boolean for Admin Priveleges

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, models

In my app there's a user model with an admin role. I want admins to be able to create new admins, so on the users/edit page I'm hoping to create an admin-visible checkbox that, when checked turns the user into an admin. The code I'm using is here. Everything works other than the checkbox bit, which is why I'm asking. I'm new to Rails, and I just can't figure out how to scrape the admin checkbox info and use it to alter the admin attribute (which is attr_protected for security reasons).

My edit form

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <% if signed_in? %>
        <% if current_user.admin? %>
          <h3> Click to Switch On/Off Admin  
          <%= check_box_tag(:admin) %></h3>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit @string, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The relevant lines of my user.rb file

```
before_save :toggle_admin

private

    def toggle_admin
      if self.admin == true
        self.toggle!(:admin)
      end
    end
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't toggle anything when I submit.

Thanks!

Sasha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually problem is because you had added **:admin checkbox** incorrectly. You have to do it like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :admin %>
```

It will produce input with correct name:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="user_admin" name="user[admin]" value="0" />
```

So then you will have correct params hash which is sent after form submission.

For additional details please check Rails documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

**Update #1**

If in your case you want to use toggle for security reasons, just change `before_save` to `after_save`, because toggle works like this:

```
User.last.toggle!(:admin)
```

SQL output:

```
1.9.3p194 :007 > User.last.toggle!(:admin)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (83.8ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `admin` = 1 WHERE `users`.`id` = 13
 => true 

1.9.3p194 :008 > User.last.toggle!(:admin)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (76.7ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `admin` = 0 WHERE `users`.`id` = 13
```

**Update #2**

In principle, you can implement it using a virtual attribute for checkbox.

```
after_save :toggle_admin
attr_accessor :adminify
attr_accessible :adminify

private

    def toggle_admin
      if self.adminify == "1"
        self.toggle!(:admin)
      end
    end
```

Check tutorial about virtual attributes in Rails: http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely going in the right direction, cause I'm now getting a "Can't assign mass attributes" error. The trouble, though, is how to record that response and then use it in my user.rb file through the "toggle" line, without actually "assigning" a value to the attribute in my form. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you don't want to assign admin attribute directly through the form? In any case :admin attribute value is already assigned before `before_save :toggle_admin` is being processed, so you are toggling it back.

Comment: I don't want to assign directly, because I'm basing this authentication system on Hartl's tutorial, and he suggests that having admin be an accessible attribute is a security flaw that could allow hackers to alter the attribute, if they know what they're doing. Didn't quite understand the reasoning, but I trust his logic, and I've been struggling to implement a solution that aligns with it.

Comment: "Explicitly defining accessible attributes is crucial for good site security. If we omitted the attr_accessible list in the User model (or foolishly added :admin to the list), a malicious user could send a PUT request as follows: put /users/17?admin=1"

Comment: You don't need to explain me how I can break security in this case. I just wanted to point why your attribute value is not being updated properly because I don't know how your architecture is being build. I had updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry. I just meant to explain why I'm making life more difficult for myself. At any rate, there's still the mass-assign error ("Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin"), because I'm trying to save the checkbox info. Any idea how to get around that? Or how to temporarily save that value in a variable that isn't f?

Comment: It is ok, just want to help you! You can use virtual attribute, check my update. Hope it helps.